# A C-algo overflows the memory

Tags: c, overflow

I am working on a simple algorithm on an online codeschool. The following algorithm works just fine on my Xcode console, but the online platform outputs that I am overflowing the memory. The following code deals with a screening of a stock. (I first used malloc dynamic allocation, but after this message, I used simple arrays, see below).

Let's say you have a stock of N products. Suppose the initial stock is set by a one-dimensional array of size N, (`c[i], i between 0 and N-1`). Now suppose there are M operations, each of which is represented by two entries : the index of the product, and the number of product which are inputed. The results outputs the final state of each product of the stock. Here's an example :

Input :

3 (number of products)
4 6 3 (4 items of the product '1', 6 of the product '2',...)
2 (number of operations)
2 3 (3 elements more of product '2')
1 -1 (1 elements minus of product '1')

Output :

3 (4-1 left of product '1')
9 (6+3 left of product '2')
3 (of product '3')

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{   int i,j,N,M;
    //Number of products
    scanf("%d",&N);
    //Initial stock of each product
    int c[N];
    //Input if the user
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &c[i]);}
    //Outputs's result
    int res[N];
    //Initializing the output res
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        res[i] = c[i];}
    //Number of operations
    scanf("%d",&M);
    //Each operation represented by the index of the product, and the number elements of the        //latter
    int d[M][2];
    //A loop to update at each step the stock
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d", &d[i][0],&d[i][1]);}
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
                res[d[i][0]-1] = res[d[i][0]-1] + d[i][1];}
    //Printing the result
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%d ",res[i]);}
}
```

Does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: Use `malloc()` instead of VLAs...

Comment: I know, I used it, but the result was :'overflowing the memory because of use of dynamic allocation'

Comment: Could you post the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: It is in french but a translation would be : memory access out of the allowed zone

Comment: @Newben Please, post the exact message :) I speak French.

Comment: For @H2CO3, in french :Votre programme a échoué à la suite d'un accès mémoire en dehors des zones réservées, ou d'un dépassement de la limite de mémoire.
Votre programme s'est terminé à la suite d'une erreur. Cela peut venir d'une des raisons suivantes :
Votre programme a dépassé la limite de mémoire autorisée pour ce problème, que ce soit sous la forme de variables statiques, d'allocations dynamiques, ou bien de la pile.
Votre programme a tenté de faire un accès mémoire en dehors des zones allouées

Comment: @Newben: also, do you get a similar message or problem with the code you posted?  If not, then you need to post the code that produces the problem (there's not much point troubleshooting the code that doesn't).

Comment: e.g. the error is a "seg fault"

Comment: @Newben Thanks! Well, I'd rather translate it as "Your program has failed (executing) either during accessing memory which was reserved or by requesting too much memory." <- I'd say the 1st reason which you omitted from your translation is actually more likely, i. e. it's a segfault.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes I get the same message with the code I posted

Comment: Ok, so the code is not optimal so that it uses too much memory. This is it ?

Comment: Its not too much memory. You are indexing past the end of one of those arrays.

Comment: At least using the input provided by the OP the code runs fine. `gcc` is quiet and `valgrind` is content. (`x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`)

Comment: @Newben: are you sure you're describing the inputs correctly?  You may want to use a file for input (that you can post) so you can be sure our results are reproducible.  Using the input from the question, I get what I think is the expected output (but which is a different output than you describe).  I see an output of `3 9 3`, which represents one less of product '1' and 3 additional of product '2'.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista, sorry I am qui te confused now, where do I indexing past the end of one of the arrays ?

Comment: Oops ... - so do I. @MichaelBurr

Comment: @MichaelBurr, you're abslutely right, I have edited my post

Answer (score 3):

You don't check the range of the product indexes when you read them in in this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) { scanf("%d%d", &d[i][0],&d[i][1]);}
```

So if someone enters a product index which is out of range, the program will index past the end of the res array.

Comment: You mean I should wrap this loop by an if condition like if((0<= d[i][0]-1)&&( d[i][0]-1< N)){...} condition ? If so, I still have the same message...

Comment: You have another error then also. That check will plug at least one source of error.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to debug all the way I could, the exercise says, knowing the variable 'N' must be less than 10000, and 'M' less than 300000, the output must be obtained in less than 5s, on a 1ghz machine with 1000ko of memory. Do you think my code is not optimal ?

Comment: Your code would probably work on almost any modern machine. I looked at it and I don't see anything else wrong with it. Have you tried using "assert" to verify all of your indices before you use them?

Comment: Where does it crash? After you input everything? Or does the crashing version crash before you input all the data?

Comment: In fact, it crashes after the input of all the data (as for assert(),it worked without pb)